# C# (Windows Form) - Using ToUpper for State Abbreviation

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a textbox on my form that allows the user to enter in a state. I also have a button that I'm using to format the entered state to make sure both of the letters are capital. I was able to write some code that makes the first letter capital, but I'm having trouble getting the whole entire string (the entered state) to be capital. Here is what I used to make the first letter capital:

```
        if (state.Length > 0)
            {
                char firstChar = state[0];
                state = Char.ToUpper(firstChar) + state.Substring(1);
            }
```

This code formats only the first letter but I want the whole string to be capitalized so I tried this:

```
 String.ToUpper(state);
```

This code will not run and I get an error saying "cannot convert from string to System.Globalization.CultureInfo". I don't understand how to fix this error even after researching about it. All I know is that I need to use ToUpper to convert the whole string, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong? Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Try `state = state.ToUpper();`

Comment: You know that the TextBox control has a `CharacterCasing` property that automatically converts to uppercase or lowercase whatever you input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ToUpper` on your string will change the entire string to uppercase.

```
if (state.Length > 0)
{
    state = state.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've been trying to figure this out for so long! Does the same apply for lower case as well? Char.ToLower is for 1 character anywhere in the string and ToUpper is for the whole string?

Comment: Yes. `String.ToUpper` applies on whole string.

Comment: Yes you could go `state.ToLower();` to make the entire string lowercase.